# customtkinter - <RuntimeError: can't re-enter readline> error shows up when i try to input a list of data in my app

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary, customtkinter

So i am using the customtkinter to make a simple app that changes what ever the user wishes to change in any given excel sheet, using it's library path. To achieve that i did a simple menu, where in the 1st tab the user can simply put the single word they wish to change, and the corresponding chance word. The second one is the one where i'm having problems because i want the user to be able to input a whole list - array - dictionary ( whatever it is ), of words and their corresponding values, all put the main code and all the little variants of it that i have done.
Hope anyone can help me, i'll be here if you have any doubts.

Main code

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
import customtkinter
from pathlib import Path
import openpyxl
import json

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("System")  # Modes: "System" (standard), "Dark", "Light"
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")  # Themes: "blue" (standard), "green", "dark-blue"


class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    
        
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        def btn1():
            BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).parent
            INPUT_DIR = BASE_DIR / f"{self.path.get()}"  # !!! Adjust file path !!!
            OUTPUT_DIR = BASE_DIR / f"{self.path.get()}"

            # Create output directory
            OUTPUT_DIR.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

            replacement_pair = {
            f"{self.find.get()}": f"{self.repl.get()}"
            }
            

            files = list(INPUT_DIR.rglob("*.xls*"))
            for file in files:
                wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
                for ws in wb.worksheets:
                    for row in ws.iter_rows():
                        for cell in row:
                            if cell.value in replacement_pair.keys():
                                cell.value = replacement_pair.get(cell.value)
                wb.save(OUTPUT_DIR / f"{file.stem}.xlsx")
                print(f"{self.find.get()}")
        
        def btn2():
    
            # Get input for the pairs, one pair per line
            pairs_input = input(f"{self.textbox.get('0.0', 'end')}")

            pairs = {}
            while True:
                if pairs_input.lower() == 'done':
                    break
                try:
                    word, item = map(str.strip, pairs_input.split(',', 1))
                    pairs[word] = item
                except ValueError:
                    print("stfu")
                
                pairs_input = input()

            # Display the pairs in JSON format
            json_output = json.dumps(pairs, indent=2)
            print("JSON output")
            print(json_output)

            BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).parent
            INPUT_DIR = BASE_DIR / f"{self.path.get()}"  # !!! Adjust file path !!!
            OUTPUT_DIR = BASE_DIR / f"{self.path.get()}"

            # Create output directory
            OUTPUT_DIR.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

            replacement_pair = json_output
            

            files = list(INPUT_DIR.rglob("*.xls*"))
            for file in files:
                wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
                for ws in wb.worksheets:
                    for row in ws.iter_rows():
                        for cell in row:
                            if cell.value in replacement_pair.keys():
                                cell.value = replacement_pair.get(cell.value)
                wb.save(OUTPUT_DIR / f"{file.stem}.xlsx")
                

        # configure window
        self.title("Find and Replace")
        self.geometry(f"{500}x{525}")

        # configure grid layout (4x4)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure((2, 3), weight=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure((0, 1, 2), weight=1)

        # create tabview
        self.tabview = customtkinter.CTkTabview(self, width=250)
        self.tabview.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=(20, 10), pady=(20, 10), sticky="nsew")
        self.tabview.add("Tab 1")
        self.tabview.add("Tab 2")
        self.tabview.add("Tab 3")
        self.tabview.tab("Tab 1").grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)  # configure grid of individual tabs
        self.tabview.tab("Tab 2").grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.tabview.tab("Tab 3").grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # single replace
        self.find = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self.tabview.tab("Tab 1"), placeholder_text="Find")
        self.find.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=(20, 10))
       
        self.repl = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self.tabview.tab("Tab 1"), placeholder_text="Replace")
        self.repl.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=(20, 10))
        
        self.path = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self.tabview.tab("Tab 1"), placeholder_text="Path")
        self.path.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=20, pady=(20, 10))

        self.button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.tabview.tab("Tab 1"), text="Replace", command=btn1)
        self.button.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=(20, 10))
        
        # mass replace
        self.textbox = customtkinter.CTkTextbox(self.tabview.tab("Tab 2"), width=250)
        self.textbox.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(5, 5), pady=(0, 0), sticky="nsew")

        #self.textbox2 = customtkinter.CTkTextbox(self.tabview.tab("Tab 2"), width=250)
        #self.textbox2.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=(5, 5), pady=(0, 0), sticky="nsew")

        self.path2 = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self.tabview.tab("Tab 2"), placeholder_text="Path")
        self.path2.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=20, pady=(20, 10))

        self.button2 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.tabview.tab("Tab 2"), text="Replace", command=btn2)
        self.button2.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=(20, 10))
        

    def open_input_dialog_event(self):
        dialog = customtkinter.CTkInputDialog(text="Type in a number:", title="CTkInputDialog")
        print("CTkInputDialog:", dialog.get_input())

    def change_appearance_mode_event(self, new_appearance_mode: str):
        customtkinter.set_appearance_mode(new_appearance_mode)

    def change_scaling_event(self, new_scaling: str):
        new_scaling_float = int(new_scaling.replace("%", "")) / 100
        customtkinter.set_widget_scaling(new_scaling_float)

    def sidebar_button_event(self):
        print("sidebar_button click")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

This is an example of the list a want to be able to make, but instead of putting it directly in the code, the user should do it trough the app

```
from pathlib import Path
import openpyxl

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).parent
INPUT_DIR = BASE_DIR / "E:\XPD Global\Find_Replace\Change"  # !!! Adjust file path !!!
OUTPUT_DIR = BASE_DIR / "E:\XPD Global\Find_Replace\Change"

# Create output directory
OUTPUT_DIR.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

replacement_pair = {
  "AL": "Alabama",
  "NY,": "New York",
  "MS": "Mississippi",
  "ESTONIA": "Estonia",
  "SOFIA": "Sofia",
  "PRAGA": "Prague",
  "WARSAW": "Warsaw",
  "CT": "Connecticut",
  "OH": "Ohio",
  "ILLINOIS": "Illinois",
  "CDMX": "Ciudad de México",
  "Mty": "Monterrey",
  "NC": "North Carolina",
  "CALIFORNIA": "California",
  "UTAH": "Utah",
  "MINNESOTA": "Minnesota",
  "FLORIDA": "Florida",
  "COLORADO": "Colorado",
  "TAIWAN": "Taiwan",
  "MICHIGAN": "Michigan",
  "COLORADO": "Colorado",
  "KENTUCKY": "Kentucky",
  "HOUSTON": "Houston",
  "ROCKFORD": "Rockford",
  "KOWLOON BAY": "Kowloon Bay",
  "ITASCA,": "Itasca",
  "EL PASO": "El Paso",
  "SARASOTA": "Sarasota",
  "CLEVELAND": "Cleveland",
  "SOUTHFIELD": "Southfield",
  "SAN ANTONIO": "San Antonio",
  "BROOKLYN": "Brooklyn",
  "NORTH BAY VILLAGE": "North Bay Village",
  "FORT LAUDERDALE": "Fort Lauderdale",
  "GREER": "Greer",
  "RIVERHEAD": "Riverhead",
  "HIALEAH": "Hialeah",
  "OSCEOLA": "Osceola",
  "FARMINGDALE": "Farmingdale",
  "TORRANCE": "Torrance",
  "AUSTIN": "Austin",
  "CITY OF INDUSTRY": "City of Industry",
  "STELERING": "Sterling",
  "BLAIRSVILLE": "Blairsville",
  "NOVI": "Novi",
  "MARIETTA": "Marietta",
  "MIAMI": "Miami",
  "DONNELSVILLE": "Donnelsville",
  "LOS ANGELES": "Los Angeles",
  "HYPOLUXO": "Hypoluxo",
  "POMPANO BEACH": "Pompano Beach",
  "LAS VEGAS": "Las Vegas",
  "CHICAGO": "Chicago",
  "SUMMERVILLE": "Summerville",
  "DES PLAINES": "Des Plaines",
  "LONGVIEW": "Longview"
}
 

files = list(INPUT_DIR.rglob("*.xls*"))
for file in files:
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
    for ws in wb.worksheets:
        # Iterate over the columns and rows, search for the text and replace
        for row in ws.iter_rows():
            for cell in row:
                if cell.value in replacement_pair.keys():
                    cell.value = replacement_pair.get(cell.value)
    wb.save(OUTPUT_DIR / f"{file.stem}_NEW.xlsx")
```

This is the simples form of it, just replacing what it's in the code

```
import openpyxl

replacement_pair = {"Nombre": "Name", "Text": "Texto"}  # !!! Change this !!!

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("Check.xlsx")  # !!! Adjust file name !!!
for ws in wb.worksheets:
    # Iterate over the columns and rows, search for the text and replace
    for row in ws.iter_rows():
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value in replacement_pair.keys():
                cell.value = replacement_pair.get(cell.value)
wb.save("Check.xlsx")
```

This one is somewhat of what i have tried in the main code, so in the app's text box i would put the list and when finished, put a "done"

```
import json

def main():
    # Get input for the pairs, one pair per line
    pairs_input = input("Enter word and item pairs (word, item) on each line. Type 'done' to finish:\n")

    pairs = {}
    while True:
        if pairs_input.lower() == 'done':
            break

        try:
            word, item = map(str.strip, pairs_input.split(',', 1))
            pairs[word] = item
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Please enter pairs in the format 'word, item'.")
        
        pairs_input = input()

    # Display the pairs in JSON format
    json_output = json.dumps(pairs, indent=2)
    print(json_output)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have tried a bunch os options, none of witch seemed to work, i'm out of ideas, also not realy proficient in coding, still learning and am very stuck in this

This is the error im getting

````
 File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\ctk_button.py", line 554, in _clicked
    self._command()
  File "e:\XPD Global\XPDtryouts\Test.py", line 45, in btn2
    pairs_input = input(f"{self.textbox.get('0.0', 'end')}")
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: can't re-enter readline
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\ctk_button.py", line 554, in _clicked
    self._command()
  File "e:\XPD Global\XPDtryouts\Test.py", line 45, in btn2
    pairs_input = input(f"{self.textbox.get('0.0', 'end')}")
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^```
````

Comment: Why are you using `input()` here?  That's for getting input from a terminal - you've already retrieved the user-entered data from the Text widget, you should *use that directly* rather than passing it to `input()`.

Comment: @jasonharper You mean in this line?
pairs_input = input(f"{self.textbox.get('0.0', 'end')}")
I'm not shure why, saw it on a couple forums and tried it out...